# AutoComplete Textbox with DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, autocomplete, textbox

I want to make `AutoComplete` in `TextBox` like that picture. It is `DataGridView` in autocomplete. How to do that thing?

[image]

Comment: No, I want to make autocomplete like datagridview not a listview

Comment: Look at that answer. It is for `DataGrid` that is similar to `DataGridView`.

Comment: Can you be more specific? `AutoComplete` means you start typing and a complete text formulated from your partial text is suggested as I've shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28351038/3773066). Or - as S.Akbari referred to and what your image appears to allude to - are you wanting to `Filter` your grid data based on the `TextBox` text? I've shown filtering in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31818204/3773066). There are already *lots* of SO discussions on filtering `DataGridView` data btw.